# R Studio (on EC2 cloud) can't download data to RDS using rmysql

Tags: mysql, r, amazon-web-services

I'm using Amazon EC2 to run a version of R Studio. I followed the instructions for set-up [here](http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/). Super easy to set up.

I also have an Amazon RDS running on the cloud.

I'm trying to write some data from the cloud version of R studio to the database using the rMySQL package. The code to connect to the DB is below. Username and password are blocked out obviously.

```
con <- RMySQL::dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
                 user = '*****',
                 password = '*****',
                 host = 'mydbinstance3.cuedemsy5i52.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
                 dbname='dbnamez')
```

The code runs quickly on my desktop, but there is a long delay on the cloud, followed by this error:

> Error in .local(drv, ...) : Failed to connect to database: Error:
>   Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   'mydbinstance3.cuedemsy5i52.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (110)

What does this mean? Can someone help me make this work? Thanks!

Comment: Have you opened up your RDS instance to all incoming IP address on port 3306?  To test this, try connecting to your RDS MySQL instance directly from the command line of the same computer where R is running.  If that doesn't work, then fix that problem first.

Comment: Hi, the RDS instance is open on port 3306. As I mentioned in the post, I can connect quickly from my desktop copy of R Studio.

Comment: I think it's the fact that the rds and EC2 area on different VPCs. I'll try this.